# Profile windows 7 booting

Tags: windows, boot, performance

My windows 7 boot very slow (stage when windows desktop appear), it need something about 10 minutes, to start working normal. Do you know any software to profile/analyze windows booting time ? I want to check which applications/services takes the most booting time and why.

Comment: Have you tried `msconfig` or [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/bb963902)? Are your drivers up to date? Do you have unplugged shared printers? Are you sure you have no malware? We need more info

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Windows WPT](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx) and run this command:

> xbootmgr -trace boot -traceFlags
>   BASE+LATENCY+DISK_IO_INIT+DISPATCHER+FILE_IO+FILENAME+REGISTRY
>   -stackwalk profile+CSwitch+ReadyThread+DiskReadInit+DiskWriteInit+ImageLoad+ImageUnload+RegQueryKey+RegEnumerateKey+RegEnumerateValueKey+RegDeleteKey+RegCreateKey+RegOpenKey+RegSetValue+RegDeleteValue+RegQueryValue+RegQueryMultipleValue+RegSetInformation+RegFlush+RegVirtualize+RegCloseKey+RegHiveInit+RegHiveDestroy+RegHiveLink+RegHiveDirty
>   -resultPath C:\TEMP

After reboot stop the countdown, load the ETL into WPA.exe, [load the debug symbols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448108.aspx), click on "Profile"->"Apply", "browse catalog" and select the file `FullBoot.Boot.wpaprofile`

[image]

Look which boot part is too long.